# Sort Column Headers when doing PIvot

Tags: sql, pivot, teradata

I have the following SQL in Teradata SQL Assistant.  The query works ok. But the tr_date is yyyymm - year and month of the transaction. They are not coming up sorted, and I cannot put a sort in sub-query. How else can I get the column headers sorted in result? I need the column headers sorted descending for reporting purposes.

Currently, tbl1 looks like below.

| Week_start | tr_date | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022/2/6 | 202202 | 5 |
| 2022/2/6 | 202202 | 6 |
| 2022/3/14 | 202203 | 3 |
| 2022/3/21 | 202203 | 4 |
| 2022/3/23 | 202203 | 10 |

The result should be like below

| week_start | 202202 | 202203 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022/2/6 | 11 | 0 |
| 2022/3/14 | 0 | 3 |
| 2022/3/21 | 0 | 14 |

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM tbl1 
 PIVOT(
        SUM(sales) FOR tr_date IN (SELECT tr_date FROM tbl1)
      ) AS temp_pivot
 ORDER BY start_week
```

Comment: I don't know `teradata`, but believe that *conditional aggregation* would help.

Comment: There's no way to order the colums when using a subquery (and that renders this feature useless)

Comment: Thanks dnoeth. That's what I thought, but still wanted to check.

Comment: Thanks Barbaros, but the weeks keep going up so I was hoping to set it up once such that would work.